# jQuery waypoint event triggered before reaching waypoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onload

I seem to be having problems with properly executing a waypoint event. It executes before I even reach the waypoint. The strange thing is; I set a console.log to see if it waits for the waypoint and that works just fine. So the function does execute at the right moment but the fadeIn executes as soon as the document is ready. 
Javascript and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#trigger").waypoint(function(down){
    $("p#ptje").fadeIn(4000).removeClass("hidden");

    triggerOnce:true;
    offset:'50%';

});

});
```

Can anyone help me determine why it is executing one part immediately on load and the other part on the waypoint properly?
The site is already up: athena.fhict.nl/users/i303973/PASS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your index.js you are removing the hidden class from all `p.hidden`. Removing that should allow to to be shown when the waypoint is activated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.hidden").fadeIn(1500).removeClass("hidden");
    $("h1.hidden").fadeIn(1500,function(){
        //the line below is what is causing the paragraph to be shown before 
        //you scroll down to the waypoint 
        $("p.hidden").fadeIn(1500).removeClass("hidden");
        $("img#arrowdown").fadeIn(1500).removeClass("hidden")
    }).removeClass("hidden");
    $("#cssmenu").sticky({topSpacing:0});       
});
```